# HTML/CSS Divs moving on browser resize

Tags: html, css

I have two divs that I need to fill a page. One of them resizes automatically, and the other has a fixed with. The one that resizes is on the left, and the fixed one is on the right. This works perfect when the browser is at full screen, but if I resize the browser to a certain size, the resizing one moves far right underneath the fixed div, while the fixed div is in the correct spot. How do I get the div to stay put when the browser window is resized?

HTML:

```
<div class=wrapper>
    <div class=right>
        Right Fixed Sidebar
    </div>

    <div class=main>
        Main Resizing Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
margin-top: 25px;
min-width: 630px;
}
.main{
overflow: hidden;
font-family: "Gill Sans","Gill Sans MT",Calibri,sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 100;
margin-left: 25px;
height: 250px;
background: green;
}
.right{
float: right;
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
font-family: "Gill Sans","Gill Sans MT",Calibri,sans-serif;
text-align: center;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
background: orange;
}
```

Comment: what browser support do you need? can u suffice with IE9+, or do u need IE8-?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea IE8+ would be good, how much more difficult is it to get it to work?

Comment: with IE9+. there is a ridiculously easy solution. ill post an answer, hopefully itll help.

Comment: alright posted an answer, however for an IE8 fallback ... will u accept a JS solution? or must it be CSS-only?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Thanks for the answer, javascript will work for IE8.

Comment: alright, edited my answer to include a JS fallback. CSS-only is totally doable, just a crapton of effort for such little gain haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as long as you can deal with IE9+ (and all real browsers, with the exception of the Android browser < 4.4), you can do something pretty simple, but mega powerful.

HTML:

```
<div class=wrapper>
    <div class=main>
        Main Resizing Content
    </div><div class=right>
        Right Fixed Sidebar
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    margin-top:25px;
    min-width:630px;
    height:250px;
}

.right,
.main {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    height:100%;
}

.right {
    width:300px;
}

.main {
    width:calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

Quick explanation:

- `display:inline-block;` has all the glory of `block` elements, but can be displayed inline ... the `vertical-align:top;` is in case you wanted different heights for the elements
- you set the fixed width for the sidebar on the right
- the width of the `.main` element is using `calc()`, which does exactly what it looks like ... full-width of container minus the fixed width (which is equal to the right sidebar)

[Here is a jsFiddle showing a working model.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltowutkb/)

**Fallbacks**

The cool thing is that `display:inline-block;` works back to IE8, so the only fallback-related concern you have is setting the width.

If you are using a feature-detection library such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) (which, if you aren't, you should be), then you can do something combining CSS and JS.

JS:

```
if(!Modernizr.csscalc){
    var container = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
        main = container.querySelector('.main'),
        right = container.querySelector('.right');

    main.style.width = (container.clientWidth - right.clientWidth);
}
```

If you're using jQuery you can use its syntax, just trying to be library agnostic. If you aren't using Modernizr, you can put it in conditional comments at the bottom of the body:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var container = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
            main = container.querySelector('.main'),
            right = container.querySelector('.right');

        main.style.width = (container.clientWidth - right.clientWidth);
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Putting it at the bottom of the body avoids need to check if the document has loaded or not, you should be good with that.

Comment: Thank You very much, it works like a charm now! I would upvote your answer but don't have 15 reputation haha